# This code does not work, what am I doing wrong? Cannot create an instance of class com.example.myapplication.MainViewActivity

Tags: java, viewmodel

This code does not work, what am I doing wrong?
Error:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.myapplication.MainViewActivity

It was like that at first: 
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class); 
and it worked, but this constructor was deprecated.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MainViewActivity mainViewActivity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainViewActivity = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewActivity.class);
    }
}

public class MainViewActivity extends AndroidViewModel {
    public MainViewActivity(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }
}
```

Comment: You may have more luck getting answers to your question if you add another tag to this post which specifies the language you are using -- then people strong in this programming language can easily find it

Comment: You're not saying what went wrong. On the face of it, your code makes sense somewhat, but what happens then ? The screen is red, the phone overheat and beeps, it crashes and never start, there's an exception ? Is the exception due to MainViewActivity not having a default constructor (cannot create instance of class is usually due to that).

Comment: Can you provide a bit of clarification to why you're attempting to store the class file?